Csound : retrieving several bins from FFT
In Csound with opcode pvsbin I can retrieve single bins from FFT.
But which opcode should I use if I want to retrieve large chunks of bins from FFT simultaneously, like for instance bins 1 to 300 from a 2048 bins FFT ?
Thanks

I would use the opcodes pvs2array/pvsfromarray. You can find an example in https://flossmanual.csound.com/csound-language/arrays#operations-on-arrays (Example 03E07) which you can easily adapt, I think. (I wanted to include the main part of the code here but I am not successful inserting multi-line code in this post.)

Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for.
